# Convert json object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have the following controller:

```
public function getPrice()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('q');
    $data['price'] = $this->emodel->get_peUniformPrice($id);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

which outputs this:

```
"{\"price\":[{\"Price\":\"250\"}]}"
```

How can I make it like 250? My jQuery:

```
function showPrice(size) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('enrollment/getPrice/');?>",
        data: {
            q: size
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#txtpeUniform").val(data);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use `data.price[0].Price` to get  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that you are using jQuery.. if you want to turn the json object into a javascript object you could do something like

```
var convertedObject = $.parseJSON($data);
alert(convertedObject.Price);
```

what this effectively does is converts your Json string into a javascript object which you can reference the properties out of and the get the value from these properties.. let me give you another example

```
var jsonString = {'Firstname':'Thiren','Lastname':'Govender'};
var jObject = $.parseJSON(jsonString);
console.log(jObject.Firstname) // this will output Thiren.
console.log(jObject.Lastname) // this will output Govender.
```

modify your code

```
function showPrice(size) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('enrollment/getPrice/');?>",
        data: {
            q: size
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // make sure this is returning something..
            $("#txtpeUniform").val(data);
        },
    });
}
```

I hope this helps you..

Regards

Comment: type out what gets displayed in the log from the above modification

Comment: I posted the output in console log

Comment: Okay so its an array of prices, could you try this and give me the output. 'var priceData = $.parseJSON(data); console.log(priceData);'

Comment: it displays in the console log this {"price":[{"Price":"500"}]}

Comment: try this "$("#txtpeUniform").val(data.price[0].Price);"

Comment: this is the code success: function(data){
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      console.log(obj.price[0].Price);
       $("#txtpeUniform").val(obj.price[0].Price); // = 250

Comment: replace with this. success: function(data)
{
 $("#txtpeUniform").val(data.price[0].Price);
}

Comment: Can you help me again because when I use this in my other project all same but it doesn't output anything and in console log it says function undefined....

Answer (score 2):

The `$.ajax` method will automatically deserialise the string to an object for you, so you simply need to access the required property. Assuming that you only ever want to retrieve the first price returned in the `price` array, you can access it directly by index. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#txtpeUniform").val(data.price[0].Price); // = 250
},
```

Comment: Have you checked the network console to ensure the AJAX request is successful and that data is being returned?

Comment: this is what the console log prints Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.....

Comment: That means that the `price` property is empty, or doesn't exist. What do you see in the console if you add `console.log(data)` to the above?

Comment: this is {"price":[{"Price":"250"}]}

Comment: I am at a loss then, as that should be working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fceje6kd/

Comment: Maybe it's in my controller perhaps or the way I code my jquery?

Comment: I tried also JSON.stringify while you are posting your answer but same results...